# Prevent quick usage of tab key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a functionality which forbids users to input specific symbols into `<input>` tags and also convert all alphabet characters to uppercase.

Everything worked fine when I found out this bug with fast tabbing between elements.

**Problem:**

Whenever a user inputs a character and presses the tab key really fast, the last character won't get converted to upper case.

**Note:**

I still want to let users tab between inputs so just `e.preventDefault()` is not an option here. I need to slightly slow down the tab action with 20-30 milliseconds or so.

**Code:**

```
var $inputs = $('input[type="text"]');

$inputs.on('keyup keydown keyhold paste', function(e) {
    //validate_input will return true if character is allowed and transformed into upper case
    if (!validate_input(e, $(this))) {
        return false;
    }

    if (e.which == 9) {
       // i need to do something here to slightly slow down the tab process
       // just to make sure the above function will execute before the default tab action.
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `e.key` instead of `e.which` because that is OS/browser-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this wont solve my current problem.

Comment: Why don't you change your function to make it work even when the input doesn't have focus ?

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way. You should probably use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)-event instead.

Comment: @some if I use `.on('input')` I won't be able to get the keycode.

Comment: Why do you need the keykode? Let the user input whatever they like, and filter it in the input-event-handler. That way you get 100% working code, regardless of how the input got into the field.

Comment: The users can input into cyrillic alphabet as well. So my thoughts back then were to get the different characters by their key codes. Nevertheless my code works completely fine on transforming every alphabet to uppercase or restricting symbols. My problem here is when you type, for example, an 'n' it should get transformed to 'N'. If i type it for a second it will. But when i instanly type it and tab out to the next input it wont get transformed.

Comment: Have you tried doing it on `blur`?

Comment: @JeremyJackson I just tried it, same effect. :(

Comment: Listen, You can continue like you have done so far, trying to find every way to prevent the browser doing what it was supposed to do, trying to fix bugs, and find new bugs if the user uses another browser, or a keyboard with a foreign language, or some special helper program. Or you can change all that and use the input-event and do your check and transformation there.

Comment: By your description it seems that your function cannot change the input when it doesn't have focus, you should probably fix that instead of changing what happens when tab is used.

Comment: The function did execute when the input was focused, but after pressing tab key too fast it didn't have time to execute. Anyways `.on('input')` approach works, i've tried a basic example with it and this bug wont occur. Instead of collecting key codes i'll just create a list with allowed symbols and for each character i'll do a simple check for membership. Thank you @some. Please write a comment so i can upvote and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)-event instead. That is fired when the value has changed. You can do you filtering of allowed values there, and convert it to upper case. That is a much easier, foolproof, less buggy, browser independent, keyboard independent, assistive technology independent, approach to solve your problem.

Comment: input event is not fully supported by all browsers. blur or change event is better than input.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: @ManpreetSinghDhillon It is supported by all major browsers on input type=text. Even the old internet explorer supports it on input type=text.